# Liferay import pages - NoSouchGroupException

Tags: import, liferay

i am trying to import lar file - site pages and it fails because of NoSouchGroupException:

```
Failed Details
An unexpected error occurred with the publication process. Please check your portal and publising configuration.
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchGroupException: No Group exists with the primary key 19107
```

I am importing into blank site.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: What all options you are selecting while import?

Comment: I have changed nothing, keep default options. Thanks for answer but I already found the problem (below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, I have found the issue, maybe it will be helpfull for somebody:

Problem was (I do not understand why...) in Calendar content - although I have never set or use it. When I uncheck calendar (in choose content section), import was succesfull.